# GitLab equivalent to Jenkins Pipeline's agent dockerfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci

Is there a equivalent to the `dockerfile` Agent in GitLab?

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'svn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

([cf.](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#dockerfile))

---

Edit

Currently I have a repo that contains a Python script for CI that requires some dependencies and would like to use that image in the docker runner.

Currently I have hacked it like this, but that fails if there is more than one runner under that tag (because the image is local to the runner).

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```
stages:
  - image
  - ci

prepare:
  stage: image
  script:
    - docker build -f Containerfile --iidfile=iid .
    - echo "IID=$(cat iid)" >> iid.env"
  tags:
    - tag
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: iid.env

gen:
  stage: ci
  image: $IID
  script:
    - step
    - step
    - step
  artifacts:
    name: generated
    paths:
      - "./*.zip"
```

Comment: Why do you need that ? you can use the docker build command

Comment: I have expanded the question

Comment: I still don't see why you want to do that, and why you have two jobs, just start a container with your image and use docker exec to run your script. In the end you have 3 lines, docker build / docker run / docker exec

Comment: I'd count that as a workaround, yes, but generally I'd like to keep the flexibility of the `script` keyword.

Comment: While reducing my example I also forgot that I'd like to archive some artifacts. (One can could work-around that with `docker cp`, but that will get quite annoying if you have more than one artifact and you need add a cp and an artifacts statement for each...)